# Regularity of a singular Kaehler Einstein metric

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, ap.analysis-of-pdes, kahler-manifolds

On a manifold $X$ of general type i.e. $X$ is projective and $c_1(K_{X})$ semiample. One can construct a singular Kaehler Einstein metric $\omega_{\infty}$ in $-c_1(X)$. In particular, $\omega_{\infty}$ can be constructed as the limit of a normalized Kaehler Ricci flow, and in this case the potential $\varphi$ of $\omega_{\infty}$ is shown to be $L^{\infty}(X)$. I wonder whether it is possible to say something about $|\nabla \varphi|$ and higher derivatives of $\varphi$.

Comment: The gradient estimate is known, cf Proposition 4.1 here
https://arxiv.org/pdf/1404.0445.pdf . I am not aware of any higher order estimates.

Comment: Thank you and that is really helpful! Also the paper measures the gradient against the KE metric but I think it can be easily checked that it is actually true for any non singular metric.

Comment: no, it is crucial that the gradient be taken wrt to the KE metric (which has singularities). I see no reason why the potential should be Lipschitz.